# Spanish Language meets Parenting: ¿Cómo explicar la diferencia entre "buscar" y "encontrar" a un niño de tres años?

Tags: verbos, significado

El desarrollo lingüístico de los niños es algo fascinante. Muchas veces no te das cuenta de lo difícil que puede llegar a ser comprender algunos conceptos del idioma por lo profundamente interiorizados que los tenemos... hasta que te toca explicárselos a un niño.

La primera fue con nuestro hijo mayor cuando empezó a construir frases simples. Le dio por confundir los pronombres "yo" y "tú", porque cuando yo decía "yo" me señalaba a mí, y cuando decía "tú" le señalaba a él, y él se pensó que yo me llamaba "yo" y él se llamaba "tú", y por tanto a mí me decía "yo" y a sí mismo se decía "tú". Un caos.

Ahora con tres años, y tras algunos quebraderos de cabeza, me he dado cuenta de que confunde los significados de los verbos "buscar" y "encontrar". He llegado a tener algunas peloteras con él dado que cuando le pedía que buscara algo él se frustraba y me decía que "es que yo no lo busco". Yo pensaba que se estaba rebelando y que no quería buscarlo, cuando lo que me quería decir era que no lograba encontrarlo. He intentado explicárselo por gestos, y jugando con él a esconder y buscar cosas, insistiendo en usar el verbo "buscar" mientras lo busca, y usando "encontrar" cuando efectivamente lo encuentra.

Sé que antes o después su cerebro aprenderá la diferencia. En todo caso, me gustaría preguntaros: **¿tan aproximados son los significados de los verbos "buscar" y "encontrar" como para que un niño los confunda? ¿Cómo se le podría explicar a un niño de tres años la diferencia entre ambos, para que aprenda el significado correcto de ambos?** Incluso para los adultos los significados se pueden solapar: a fin de cuentas, cuando decimos "tengo que buscarlo" y "tengo que encontrarlo", en realidad con las dos frases estamos queriendo decir lo mismo, las diferencias entre ambas pueden ser más sutiles de lo que parece.

Comment: Yo he oído a gente decir buscar en lugar de encontrar (no precisamente niños) no sé si los confunden o se usa así en algún sitio. Pienso que podrías decirle que hasta que no tenga el objeto en su mano no lo ha encontrado, o hasta que lo vea al menos.

Comment: @blonfu en realidad los verbos hasta cierto punto son intercambiables: si no sabes dónde está una cosa lo mismo puedes decir "tengo que buscarlo" que "tengo que encontrarlo". Por supuesto, hay diferencias entre ambas frases, pero creo que son más sutiles de lo que parece, dado que, si lo piensas, estás diciendo lo mismo en ambas.

Comment: Pero no es ese el caso, he oído gente que dice "¡Ya he buscado la pelota!" en el momento de encontrarla.

Comment: @blonfu es comprensible: como la ha encontrado ya ha terminado de buscarla. En este caso "ya he buscado" = "ya he terminado de buscarla" = "ya la he encontrado". El fin de la acción de buscar a menudo (aunque no siempre) implica encontrar.

Comment: Si lo ves así no hay mucha diferencia entonces y ya te estás respondiendo en parte a si se pueden confundir, para mi son dos acciones muy distintas.

Comment: @walen si los verbos se confunden incluso hasta por adultos, es que algo de solape tienen. Puede ser interesante ver esta pregunta desde el punto de vista de averiguar cuál es el posible solape, y tratar de entender por qué algunos los confunden. En ese sentido considero que la pregunta sí puede aportar al sitio. Además, aunque trate de pedagogía será orientada hacia la enseñanza del idioma. Averiguar cómo hacer que alguien aprenda español correctamente (aunque sea un niño pequeño) sí lo considero dentro del propósito del sitio. En todo caso, sabéis que yo me atengo a lo que opine la mayoría.

Comment: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DGaleano conozco el sitio, la pregunta está etiqueta como "crossover" por eso, por ser una pregunta que puede hacerse en cualquiera de los dos sitios.

Comment: Disculpa pero para mi es off-topic una pregunta del tipo **¿Como explicar a un niño...**. No es una pregunta sobre español sino sobre pedagogía, educación, crianza, etc.

Comment: @DGaleano no hay nada que disculpar. Si la gente piensa que es _offtopic_ y no le veis sentido aquí, por favor, que no os tiemble el dedo y votad para que sea migrada o cerrada. A veces pregunto cosas bordeando los límites del sitio (soy consciente), y a veces acertaré y a veces no. Eso sí, dadme tiempo para traducirla si decidís migrarla.

Comment: Yo creo que es una pregunta válida. Cómo explicar la diferencia de dos conceptos que se puedan confundir tiene que ver con el idioma

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en México se dice más **"encontrar"**, que **"buscar"**. Básicamente ambas palabras conducen a lo mismo.

Yo diferencio las dos palabras de este modo, puede que me equivoque:

### Buscar:

> Movilizarse para encontrar algo perdido.

### Encontrar:

> Hallar algo. (no implica una búsqueda).

Buscar es moverse para encontrar algo perdido, y encontrar no implica un emprendimiento, uno puede encontrar algo sin haberlo buscado.
      Insisto, uno busca algo que se le pierde, esto se puede encontrar o no. Pero encontrar no implica una búsqueda necesariamente.

Answer (score -1):

Parece que tienes dos hijos.  Qué bien.  Tendrás la oportunidad de probar algo diferente con hijo número dos: No uses pronombres hasta que el niño esté listo.  Generalmente empieza esta etapa alrededor de los tres años.  Ejemplo (suponiendo que tu hijo se llama Felipe):

> Tú: Papá está cansado.  Felipe va a leer ahora [contar la historia
> de un librito bien conocido].
>
> Felipe: Sí, sí, Felipe lee.  (Felipe "lee".)
>
> Tú: Felipe lee muy bien.  ¡Gracias por leerme el cuento, Felipe!

Cuando sientas que ya es el momento, podrías jugar "Yo Tarzán, tú Jane".  Señalando con un dedo en el pecho, columpiando, dándote golpes en el pecho, con much teatro.

#### Un poco de filosofía

Los ingredientes básicos que te van a ayudar a divertirte más y tener menos frustración:

- juego
- risa
- paciencia -- entre más lees de las fases de desarrollo infantil, más paciencia tendrás, mientras esperas que el niño llegue al punto de poder captar cierto concepto

Mis hijos son trilingües y al principio me limité a una meta muy sencilla: que nos entendiéramos, a como diera lugar.  Yo cedí mucho más que ellos, aceptando muchos "errores", con tal de que pudiéramos entendernos, quién sabe cómo.

Si observas con cuidado, podrás percatar momentos en que el niño está listo para mejorar su manejo del idioma en cierto aspecto.  En ese momento, usa esas palabras o construcciones delante de él para meter lo correcto en su oído.

No hay que dar correcciones, sino simplemente modelar lo correcto, haciendo preguntas.  Ejemplo:

> Niño (4 años): ¡Yo sí sabo dónde está!
>
> Tú: ¿Ah, sí?  ¿Sabes dónde está?
>
> Niño: ¡Sí, sí!  ¡Yo sí sabo!
>
> Tú: ¿Y yo?  ¿Yo también sé dónde está?

Y déjalo ahí.  Modelaste lo correcto -- misión cumplida.  No te metas en discusiones necias.

Para separar *buscar* y *encontrar*: jugar a escondidas con mil variantes.

Mientras tanto, si tú sabes que tu hijo confunde dos palabras, trata de captar *su idea* sin *nitpicking*.  Escucha con el corazón, no como lingüista.

Si quieres, puedes aunar caras y gestos a las palabras difíciles.  Buscar: preocupación; pon una mano en la frente, palma abajo, como si hiciera mucho sol.  Encontrar: gran alegría.

No dés exlicaciones lógicas.  Eso sería dar correciones.

---

Las preguntas en negritas:

> ¿Tan aproximados son los significados de los verbos "buscar" y "encontrar" como para que un niño los confunda?

Bueno, evidentemente, ya que tu hijo los confundió, sí.

> ¿Cómo se le podría explicar a un niño de tres años la diferencia entre ambos, para que aprenda el significado correcto de ambos?

Con juegos, como ya describí:

> 1. Aunar caras y gestos a las palabras difíciles. Buscar: preocupación; pon una mano en la frente, palma abajo, como si hiciera mucho sol. Encontrar: gran alegría.
> 2. Jugar a escondidas con mil variantes.

Comment: Te agradezco tu respuesta, tiene mucha información interesante. El problema es que es la respuesta que habría esperado en el sitio de Parenting, pero no aquí. Esperaba centrar más la respuesta en los temas que resalté en negrita en la pregunta, para así tener un debate más acorde con la filosofía de este sitio. En todo caso, si me animo y publico la pregunta en Parenting te aviso para que escribas esta misma respuesta allí.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - El título dice "Spanish Language meets Parenting."  Lo que quizás me faltó agregar a mi respuesta: cuando la mamá o el papá utiliza el lenguaje meticulosamente, como tú y yo, tenemos que tener cuidado de no proyectar *nuestro* perfeccionismo a nuestro hijos, y hacer un esfuerzo conciente de llegar a un ámbito de juego y diversión, donde podemos apreciar al niño por quien es.